# add workbox-webpack-plugin config into webpack config without eject by react-app-rewired to add workbox injectManifest plugin

Tags: reactjs, webpack, workbox-webpack-plugin

### add injectManifest plugin from workbox into webpack config by config-overrides.js cuz i dont want to enject my project

**warrning:** i'am new at this.

i am looking for war to add some config to insert injectManifest plugin into my webpack configs without ejecting webpack setting and finally i find plugin thats name is **react-app-rewired** 
and this plugin give me a method to add some config but i ddint know how to add my configs i try a simple way but i got an error when i try to rum **npm start**.

```
const { InjectManifest } = require("workbox-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
   //do stuff with the webpack config...

   config["plugins"].push(

   new InjectManifest({
   swSrc: "./src/sw.js"
  })

);
 return config;
};
```

but i got error in console like this:

```
> react-gentelella@0.1.0 start /home/fibo/Documents/m_reacjs_tesaa
> react-app-rewired start

Failed to compile.

Cannot read property 'make' of undefined

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-gentelella@0.1.0 start: `react-app-rewired start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-gentelella@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/fibo/.npm/_logs/2020-03-04T13_10_36_994Z-debug.log
```